# Пропорционально высота блока относительно ширины

Tags: css, css3

Как реализовать чтобы при уменьшении ширины блока пропорционально уменьшалась и высота?

```css
.cont{
    max-width: 700px;
    border: 1px black solid;
    height: 400px;
}
```

```html
     <div class="cont">
     </div>
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/iiil/4PFt7/

Answer (score 2):

```css
.cont {
  max-width: 700px;
  border: 1px black solid;
}

.cont div {
  height: 0;
  padding-top: calc(400 / 700 * 100%)
}
```

```html
<div class="cont">
  <div></div>
</div>
```

Comment: зачем вложенный див? почему `padding-top`? откуда числа 400 и 700? было бы замечательно, если бы вы это всё объяснили и указали, что это т. н. CSS-шлюз.